# Does a Nat 20 hit on a dodge action?

Tags: dnd-5e, critical-hit

If a player uses Dodge every attack made against it gets disadvantage, but a Nat 20 is considered an auto hit.  Would this mean that the 20 would have to be rerolled or would the attack make it through the dodge?

Comment: Hi DMRob, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] to find out how things work, and visit the [help] for more guidance. Do the answers to this other question answer your question? If not, can you let us know what you want to know that those other answers don't cover?

Answer (score 12):

You don't *reroll* anything when you have Disadvantage. You roll two dice and use the lower one, so if one is a 20 and the other is a lower number (which it'll probably be) then yes, you use the lower one and won't score the automatic critical hit.

From the [SRD](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Advantage_and_Disadvantage)

> Sometimes a special ability or spell tells you that you have advantage or disadvantage on an ability check, a saving throw, or an attack roll. When that happens, you **roll a second d20** when you make the roll. Use the higher of the two rolls if you have advantage, and **use the lower roll** if you have disadvantage.

Comment: I think it's worth making a distinction between what you're doing logically vs. physically. If you only own a single d20, then physically you have to roll it and then reroll it to get 2 results. But logically, you're pretending that you rolled 2 separate dice and discarded one of them. It seems obvious, but it might trip up someone who's not used to thinking in abstract terms.